# Determine which are true and which are false | Graph Theory

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

From the following statements determine which are true and which are false. In each case justify your answer or give a counterexample.

a) If a connected graph has cut vertices, then also it has bridges.

b) If in a connected graph there are two cut edges that affect in the same vertex $u$, then $u$ is a cut vertex.

c) If in a connected graph every edge is a bridge then $G$ has cycles.

d) If $G$ is disconnected and bipartite then each component of $G$ is bipartite.

e) If in a graph $G$ the degree of each vertex is even then $G$ has bridges.

I have some ideas for the exercise (but I don't know if they are correct) ... For (a) it is not true in general. Let's consider two cycles together so that they have a common vertex, then we have a cut vertex but not a bridge. For (c) it is not true in general. Consider the star graph of order 4, $ S_4 $. Every edge is a bridge, but it does not contain cycles. For (e) it is not true in general. If we consider the cycle graph of order 3, $ C_3 $, we note that the degree of each vertex is even, but the graph has no bridges. For (d) I'm sure it's true, but I don't know how to explain it. And for the rest, I don't know.

Comment: Can you provide definitions for:
- cutting edge
- cutting vertex 
- disconnected bipartite

Comment: @JackNeubecker Let $G$ be a connected graph. A vertex $v \in G$ is called a cut vertex of  $G$, if $G-v$ (Delete $v$ from $G$) results in a disconnected graph. Removing a cut vertex from a graph breaks it in to two or more graphs. A bridge or cut-edge, is an edge of a graph whose deletion increases the graph's number of connected components. Equivalently, an edge is a bridge if and only if it is not contained in any cycle.

Comment: So a cutting edge is just a cut-edge, and a cutting vertex is just a cut-vertex? There is no reason to use two different jargon words for the same object. How about disconnected bipartite, is this just *disconnected and bipartite*?

Comment: A disconnected bipartite, as it would be an disconnected bipartite graph. That is, there is at least one vertex that is not connected. Explain me?

Comment: Is there any special meaning to saying $u$ is *the* cut-vertex? It is easy to construct an example where it is not the only cut-vertex. But it is *a* cut vertex, as by removing $u$ you also remove the two cut-edges adjacent to $u$. By the fact they are cut-edges, this disconnects the graph. As for (d), consider the partition of $V(G)$, namely $V_1$ and $V_2$. Then consider any connected component $C$. $V_1 \cap V(C)$ and $V_2 \cap V(C)$ partitions $V(C)$, and by definition, there are no edges between $V_1$ and $V_2$, so no edges between $V_1 \cap V(C)$ and $V_2 \cap V(C)$.

Comment: So we can conclude that each component of G is bipartite?

Comment: there exists a partition of the vertices of each component such that there are no edges within either set of the partition, so yes, each component is bipartite. I made a grammatical error in the above comment, but I have corrected it is the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

b) True: $V - u$ does not contain the edges adjacent to $u$. As these edges are cut-edges, $V - u$ is disconnected. Thus, $u$ is a cut-vertex. It is not unique however.

d) True: Consider the partition of $V(G)$, namely $V_1$ and $V_2$. Then consider any connected component $C$. $V_1 \cap V(C)$ and $V_2 \cap V(C)$ partitions $V(C)$, and by definition, there are no edges within $V_1$ or $V_2$, so no edges within $V_1 \cap V(C)$ or $V_2 \cap V(C)$.

The counterexamples you give for a,c,e are correct.